# What kind of HTTP responses can I use for VAST video events?

Tags: event-handling, html5-video

I am implementing an event handler to handle event callbacks for video ads served using the IAB standardized [Video Ad Serving Template](http://www.iab.net/media/file/VASTv3.0.pdf).

All I can find documenting these events is that they are configured in the VAST template as a URL.

I have to return some valid HTTP response, the simplest being a 200 with no content. Can I return other valid success responses? In particular, can I return a 302 redirect and rely on the redirect happening?

**Edit:**

For example, assume I have the following event configured in my VAST tag:

```
<TrackingEvents>
  <Tracking event=”firstQuartile”>
    <![CDATA[http://adserver.com/firstQuartile]>
  </Tracking>
</TrackingEvents>
```

If I am implementing the server at adserver.com, and responding to an HTTP call to the /firstQuartile URI stem, can I return a 302 redirect?

Comment: P.S. Sorry about the tags -- I couldn't find anything that seemed particularly relevant.

Comment: Are you talking about trackingEvents?

Comment: Yes, @Jbalsas, I'm trying to figure out how to handle trackingEvents properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use 200. You could theoretically send any response code, but the standard does not require the video player do anything about it. From the relevant section in the [VAST 3.0 spec](http://www.iab.net/media/file/VASTv3.0.pdf) (section 2.2.5, emphasis mine):

> The video player must send requests to the URIs provided in tracking elements; **however, the video player is not required to do anything with the response that is returned**. The response is only to acknowledge an event and to comply with the HTTP protocol. This response is typically a 200 with a 1x1 pixel image in the response body (although the response could be of any other type).

If your intention is to share tracking events among multiple servers, the VAST spec provides an alternative, by way of multiple `<Tracking>` events of the same type, which must be requested by video players at the same time (section 2.3.1.8):

> The use of multiple tracking events of the same kind enables the ad server to share impression tracking information with other ad serving systems such as a vendor ad servers employed by the advertiser. When multiple tracking events of the same type (i.e. multiple “start” events) are provided, the video player is required to request all events of the same type simultaneously or as close in time as possible. Any significant delay between requests may result in count discrepancies between ad serving systems.